# How to obtain certain size for a matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing

I am running a calculation and I want to achieve the result as NOJ(7x65) matrix

```
NOJ = zeros(7,65);
for x = 2:2:14
    NOJ(x,:) = (1- sqrt(1-inflow_CT))./(1+(2*kNOJfit*x/2)).^2;
end
```

this is my code it works fine but it gives me 14 points (NOJ 14x65). I only want 7 points for x=2,4,6,8,10,12,14.

[Resulting matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhCFs.png)

Does anyone know what is the reason for that?

Comment: The reason for that is that indices are always sequential and, in MATLAB, begin with 1. Why not simply make the loop `for x = 1:7`? You're dividing `x` by 2 in the calculations anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is: matrix size is being increased in the **for** loop.
For example:

```
abc=zeros(1,1); size(abc)
ans =

   1   1

abc(2,1)=4; size(abc)
ans =

   2   1
```